# Extracting Lat/Long from Bing Geocoding service

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, geocoding

I'm trying to extract the latitude and longitude information using linq to xml but for some reason my efforts fail and I can't debug the linq statement, here is the URL that returns the XML:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/UK/ST104DB?o=xml&key=AsXXdDNPzhinQEhfr9DJe_auOyXAsHr_jF8O0cjGJZDSayU8zedGhy8Vu2PzKTB9

Please could someone show me an appropriate linq statement for extracting the Latitude and Longitude values

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my I've-no-idea-what-I'm-really-doing-but-it-works first attempt

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\geo.xml"); // or from stream or wherever

XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1";
var points = (from p in xml.Descendants(ns + "Point")
              select new
                      {
                        Lat = (double) p.Element(ns + "Latitude"),
                        Long = (double) p.Element(ns + "Longitude")
                      })
               .ToList();
```

There's probably better, safer ways to do this.